# Viewport resizing on input focus on iphone · Issue (Magento version 2.2.5)

Tags: magento-2.2.5

When i click the input box the viewport changes size and the layout breaks using iphone and custom theme.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Below "meta tag" in your xml file

```
app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Hope this will help you!